# How to get alert when checkboxes in the table are not clicked and try to submit form

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I am trying to send checkbox values to other page to delete the selected rows with checkbox but when there is no checkbox clicked and try to send it should give alert for checkbox is empty and if the form is submitting after the checkbox is clicked then it should give alert whether to proceed or not this is my form

```
<form action="deleteselectedhr" name="deleteFiles" method="post" onsubmit="checkForm()">    
<table id="mytable" border=3 >
 <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
 <tr>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" id="saif" name="<c:out value="${user.hrid}" />" 
      value="<c:out value="${user.hrid}" />" />
   </td>  
</tr>
 </c:forEach>
</table>
<input TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Delete Selected HRs"/>
</form>
Javascript:
  <script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(){

    var checkt = document.getElementsById('saif');
    var chekSelect = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkt.length; i++) {
        var myElement = checkt[i];
        if (myElement.type === "checkbox" && myElement.checked) {
            if (myElement.checked) {
                chekSelect = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!chekSelect) {
        alert('Please Check Atleast one record to print cheque!!!');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>`
```

Comment: Display the `HTML` once rendered. From looking at your source code you have duplicate **ID**'s hence trying to loop though `getElementsById()` which isn't valid. Open your browser console, the errors will help you identify the problem. **getElementById()** it to target **a** specific element. (One) if you want to target multiple elements then you assign the class attribute to those elements and use `getElementsByClassName()` and then loop through them.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing the `HTML`  after the `checkbox(s)` have been rendered to the browser or without seeing the source code that creates/writes/builds those elements.

Comment: from html form i m trying to send to form data i.e checkboxes values to other page

Comment: I have even tried with getElementsByClassName() but it is not working

Comment: @manafigroup without seeing the HTML once rendered it's very hard to help you or suggest which method is best. **checkboxes in the table** the `checkbox`es shouldn't have the same **ID**. ID's are supposed to be unique. If you can display the `HTML` after rendering then I will be happy to help but until then I can't be of much use.

Comment: Use the [**required**](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html) attribute

Comment: @zer00ne if i use required then i have to select all the checkboxes and submit

Comment: @NewToJS which html are you saving in my code form is there please check that i m trying to send form data but before sending i want javascript to give alert whether checkbox is clicked or not

Comment: If validating via `javascript` you can assign a `class` name and compare it like I have in this example [**JsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/pa0uja2t/) for all checkboxes that are required have a class of required. the form will not submit unless all are checked. As suggested above you can always apply the `required` attribute to the checkboxes as shown in this example [**JsFiddle Demo- required attribute**](https://jsfiddle.net/boaddy5h/)

Comment: Is just one checkbox needed to be checked *or* is it *only one* must be checked? If the latter then use radio buttons that share a common name attribute.

Comment: **Update:** for one checkbox to be selected [**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/z63bz9jw/) this will limit to one selection only.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using a framework of any particular language.
In MVC structure, you can validate the presence of the checkbox.
For example, I am using Ruby on Rails and I have my checkbox field

```
 <%= f.label :active %>
 <%= f.check_box :active %>
```

I then validate the checkbox as

```
validates :active, presence: true
```

I can also print a flash message via my controller to show the error. Eg:-

```
flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
```

Comment: I m using servlets and jsp checkbox are in foreach loopis inside table but javascript is not working to alert if it is not checked

Comment: I used the MVC model of rails to validate the checkbox and print corresponding error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can modify here like:

- Add return to `onsubmit` like `onsubmit="return checkForm()"`
- Use class instead of id like for this demo we have used `class="item"`
- And finally use `document.querySelector` to get only checked checkbox.

**DEMO:**

```js
function checkForm() {
  if (document.querySelector('.item:checked')) {
    alert('Checkbox is checked');
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Please Check Atleast one record to print cheque!!!');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="deleteselectedhr" name="deleteFiles" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
  <table id="mytable" border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="2" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="item" value="3" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Delete Selected HRs" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think the OP is wanting multiple checkboxes to be checked. That is what I get from reading the title *"when checkbox**es** in the table are not clicked"* rather than asking  *"When **a** checkbox in the table is not selected"*

Comment: @manafigroup did you meant atleast one checkbox needs to be checked or all of them needs to checked before submit?

Comment: @NewToJS I think OP meant at least one checkbox needs to be checked since in the alert it says, "_Please Check At least one record to print cheque!!!_" but, let us wait for his confirmation.

Comment: Ah yes! Very confusing or maybe just bad formatting/planning of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkForm(e){
event.preventDefault()
var a = document.querySelectorAll('#saif');
if(a[0].checked || a[1].checked || a[2].checked == true){
alert('Checkbox  checked')
}else{
alert('Please Check Atleast one record to print cheque!!!')
}
}
```

```html
<form action="deleteselectedhr" name="deleteFiles" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm()">  
<table id="mytable" border=3 >
 <tr>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" id="saif" value="1"  /><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" id="saif" value="2"  /><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" id="saif" value="3"  />
   </td>  
</tr>
 
</table>
<input TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Delete Selected HRs"/>
</form>
```